# Redis sentinel connection is timing out from nodeJS

Tags: node.js, redis, stackexchange.redis, redis-sentinel, ioredis

Am trying to connect `redis sentinel` instance from `nodeJS` using `ioredis`. Am not able to connect redis sentinel instance despite trying multiple available options. We have not configured sentinel password. But, able to connect same redis sentinel instance from `.net core` using `StackExchange.Redis`. Please find below `nodeJS` code,

```
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import IORedis from 'ioredis';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  const ioredis = new IORedis({
    sentinels: [
      { host: 'sentinel-host-1' },
      { host: 'sentinel-host-2' },
      { host: 'sentinel-host-3' },
    ],
    name: 'mastername',
    password: 'password',
    showFriendlyErrorStack: true,
  });
  try {
    ioredis.set('foo', 'bar');
  } catch (exception) {
    console.log(exception);
  }
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

Error we got is,

```
[ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
node_modules\ioredis\built\redis\index.js:317:37)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:475:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:369:20)
    at Socket._onTimeout (node:net:481:8)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7)
```

Connection String used from `.net core` is below,

```
Redis_Configuration = "host-1,host-2,host-3,serviceName=mastername,password=password,abortConnect=False,connectTimeout=1000,responseTimeout=1000";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering this for the benefit of others. Everything is fine, but this `nodeJS` package is resolving `redis` instances into private IPs which i cannot access from my local. So, had to put it over subnet group and make it work. However, FYI - `.net core` package does not resolve into private IPs, hence i was able to access instances from my local itself.

Answer (score 0):

["The arguments passed to the constructor are different from the ones you use to connect to a single node"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ioredis/v/4.27.6#sentinel:%7E:text=the%20arguments%20passed%20to%20the%20constructor%20are%20different%20from%20the%20ones%20you%20use%20to%20connect%20to%20a%20single%20node)

Try to replace `password` with `sentinelPassword`.

Comment: @Liebale sentinelPassword is not configured. And, password param works fine from .net core as expected.